# Calories and Specific Excercise Training

Tags: exercise, calories, obesity

I have a particular exercise regiment that I currently trying out, and I would like to learn from someone else's thoughts about the number of calories I should ingest, and how much I burning in each exercise. I am currently trying an exercise regiment where I am using resistance bands, and weights. I am curling and stretching, cardio, and calisthenics (mainly situps), and I as well do lifting weights, as well as some hand exercises with a hand gripper. I typically do three sets of 20 reps and use weights, and the hand gripper as well. I typically exercise five to six days a week. My thoughts are at my BMI of 33.514, how can I crush down to get out of the obese range calories-wise,  of course, all these numbers can be theoretical I am not looking for exact here.

Comment: Google “TDEE Calculator”, that will give you a ballpark figure. Eat approximately 75-80% of your TDEE and you’ll lose weight at a good rate. Online calculators can only make educated guesses, your actual TDEE may vary. The data trends produced by your weigh-ins will indicate approximately how much you are eating in reference to your TDEE.

Comment: @JustSnilloc If you write that down as an answer I will accept it because it answers my question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weight loss is a relatively simple process that occurs in response to an energy deficit. An individual's TDEE (total daily energy expenditure) represents the total energy that a person spends each day across their many activities and metabolic processes. If these energy costs aren't counterbalanced by a sufficient caloric intake, a deficit is produced. The body still NEEDS the energy to carry out its many activities however and energy is released from the body's own stores in response to this need. This is a process that is happening constantly, but the net balance is easier to measure over the course of a day as opposed to an hour by hour assessment.

To get a ballpark figure for your TDEE, you can try any number of formulas (or calculators) that are readily available online such as [this one](https://www.freedieting.com/calorie-calculator). However, to determine your true TDEE you would want to monitor your weight. Now short term fluctuations mainly attributable to water can mask what is actually going on with body weight, but if you weigh yourself more than once a week (take an average) and look at the trend produced by 3-4 weeks worth of data you should have a pretty clear idea of where your calorie balance is with regard to your actual TDEE.

If you are considering TDEE, there is no need to calculate how many calories you are burning from exercise because such data is already included in an individuals TDEE. So don't double count your calories and make adjustments that you shouldn't. In the same vein, it is common practice for cardio machines to include how many calories you would be burning at rest into how many calories it says you are burning during exercise. While this number is technically correct, it is misleading and can cause individuals to double count their calories. A chart illustrating the approximate energy values expended during exercise may be found below.

[image]

With all that said, an energy deficit of 20-25% is a good place to be in to lose weight. Any deficit will produce weight loss, but sustainability and timeliness are important too and such a deficit strikes a good balance between the two. Therefore, if you know what your TDEE is, you can simply eat 75-80% of it and lose the weight you're trying to drop. A loss of 0.5-1.0% of your total body mass each week is also a good rate to consider and a different way of considering what the marks of good progress are. For individuals who are obese by the definition of being overfat, rates of as high as 1.5% may be appropriate, but sustainability at that rate may prove difficult. It does a person little good to have struggled for weeks and months to lose weight if they just regain it, sustainability is crucial.